# Replace ONE occurrence of something with MULTIPLE instances of something

Tags: substitute, replace

**How can you replace one match with multiple instances of a character (like `\t`)?**

It's no problem to replace multiple characters with one.
But I did not find the answer for the opposite.

For example: I want to change

```
Items: item1 item2 item3 item4
```

to

```
Items:
                item1
                item2
                ...
```

and for the whitespace I want to use `\t` tabstop (for example).
Something like:

```
:%s/\s\(item.\)/\r\t{5}\1/g
```

does not work.

Comment: Curly braces need to be escaped in patterns: `\{5}`;  unless you use *`\v`ery magic*.  (But that won't make it work in the replacement part, where you want to use it.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- You are probably best off just hitting dat <kbd>Tab</kbd> key 5 times in your example:
  `:%s/\s\(item.\)/\r`    <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>    `\1/g`
  <sub>(The tabs display as `^I` in the Command-line.)</sub>
- More elegantly, you can have vim repeat that typing for you. But with its ≥7 keystrokes and a bit of thinking effort, this technique is only economical for a bigger number of repetitions or characters to be repeated:
  `:%s/\s\(item.\)/\r`    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>`5`</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> `\t` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>    `\1/g`
- The most literal and technical answer to your question is – at the cost of even much more verbose syntax – using `\=` for substituting by an expression [[`:help sub-replace-expression`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression)], in which you could then employ the [`repeat()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#repeat()) function:
  `:%s/\s\(item.\)/\= "\n" . repeat("\t", 5) . submatch(1)/g`    <sub>(Readability spaces not required.)</sub>

Unfortunately, vim does not provide syntactic sugar for repetition (`\{5}` or otherwise) in the replacement part of the `:substitute` command;  almost none of the special regex syntax for pattern matching [[`:h pattern-overview`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#pattern-overview)] is available for the replacement: [`:h sub-replace-special`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-special)

<sub>(PS: <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>)</sub>

Comment: the number of "5" was just exemplary. I should have written 15 :)
Thanks for the helpfull and comprehensive answer. 
I really like your idea to use the <c-f> shortcut to generate the command for repetition! (stumpled over this useful shortcut some weeks ago but did't thought about it in this case) Awesome!

Comment: @eli, hey, thank you for your nice feedback! :)  I'm glad it was helpful!  (I updated the PS part to reflect the new number. ;) )